# How to extract loadingExperience and originLoadingExperience timings & percentage from google pagespeedinsights api json data?

Tags: json, performance, api, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to develop an application which uses google **Pagespeedinsights** API as the backend. When i am running the pagespeedinsights for a particular url using the command curl *https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=desired url* i am getting a json data as the response.

```
   Sample JSON response
    {
     "captchaResult": "CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED",
     "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
     "id": "https://jsonlint.com/",
     "loadingExperience": {
      "id": "https://jsonlint.com/",
      "metrics": {
       "FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS": {
        "percentile": 98,
        "distributions": [
         {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 50,
          "proportion": 0.9191070896432152
         },
         {
          "min": 50,
          "max": 250,
          "proportion": 0.05804188226370113
         },
         {
          "min": 250,
          "proportion": 0.022851028093083734
         }
        ],
        "category": "AVERAGE"
       },
       "FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS": {
        "percentile": 2784,
        "distributions": [
         {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 1000,
          "proportion": 0.5647038808001577
         },
         {
          "min": 1000,
          "max": 2500,
          "proportion": 0.3140323071688247
         },
         {
          "min": 2500,
          "proportion": 0.12126381203101773
         }
        ],
        "category": "SLOW"
       }
      },
      "overall_category": "SLOW",
      "initial_url": "https://jsonlint.com/"
     },
     "originLoadingExperience": {
      "id": "https://jsonlint.com",
      "metrics": {
       "FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS": {
        "percentile": 98,
        "distributions": [
         {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 50,
          "proportion": 0.9194600615254058
         },
         {
          "min": 50,
          "max": 250,
          "proportion": 0.05766680810438103
         },
         {
          "min": 250,
          "proportion": 0.022873130370213216
         }
        ],
        "category": "AVERAGE"
       },
       "FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS": {
        "percentile": 2774,
        "distributions": [
         {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 1000,
          "proportion": 0.5685563670116814
         },
         {
          "min": 1000,
          "max": 2500,
          "proportion": 0.3111175327063521
         },
         {
          "min": 2500,
          "proportion": 0.1203261002819664
         }
        ],
        "category": "SLOW"
       }
      },
      "overall_category": "SLOW",
      "initial_url": "https://jsonlint.com/"
     }

   I am doing it programatically.
```

String pythonScript = "import os\n" + "os.system(\"curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url="+pageSpeedMetrics.getCompanyUrl()+" > "+PYTHON_FILE_LOCATION+fileName+"\")";
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(PYTHON_FILE_LOCATION.concat(PAGESPEEDINSIGHT_PYTHON_FILE_NAME)));
                out.write(pythonScript);
                out.close();
                System.out.println(pythonScript);
                Process p = r.exec("python "+PYTHON_FILE_LOCATION.concat(PAGESPEEDINSIGHT_PYTHON_FILE_NAME)+"");
                p.waitFor();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("crux_loading_experience", jsonPagespeedInsight.getJSONObject("loadingExperience"));
        json.put("crux_origin_loading_experience", jsonPagespeedInsight.getJSONObject("originLoadingExperience"));

But when i am doing it online using **https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/** i can see the FCP & FID timing & percentage values , but in json file it is not there . How is it generated ? 
        Thanks in advance !!!